# Unity Inspector Menu Not Displaying

Tags: unity-game-engine

Steps:

1. Start Unity
2. Create a brand new file
3. Add a 3-D object
4. Click on 3-D object, inspector menu does not appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I needed to do was Window > All Layouts > Default